# Populate textarea with javascript variables from onclick

Tags: populate

I need to use an a tag to send variables to a JavaScript function which will populate a textfield, but my code doesn't seem to work.
My code,

A TAG

```
<a onclick='quote('Name', '5:03', 'Test')'>
```

TEXTAREA

```
<textarea id='quote'></textarea>
```

Javascript

```
   <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script>
function quote(username, date, quote) {
    var newText = "[quote date='" + date + "' name='" + username + "']" + quote + "[/quote]";
    var old = $("#quote").val();
    $("#quote").val(old+newText);
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Clicking just doesn't do anything?

Comment: Nope it doesn't populate the textarea @mmmmmpie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's the single quote in the anchor tag, give this a try, it seems to be fine with both `.val` and `.text`

```
<script>

function quote(username, date, quote) {        
    var newText = "[quote date='" + date + "' name='" + username + "']" + quote + "[/quote]";
    var old = $("#quote").val();
    $("#quote").val(old+newText);
}

</script>
<a onclick="quote('Name', '5:03', 'Test')">Click Here</a>

<hr/>
<textarea id='quote'></textarea>
```

Comment: @RobertMarley, I had to add the script in the html itself (inside a script tag) in the jsfiddle to have it working, here: https://jsfiddle.net/vyp0v2u4/